# Multiplication of symmetric and antisymmetric tensors times a vector, a question about indices

Tags: metric-tensor, klein-gordon-equation

I am studying the Klein-Gordon equation that is invariant under Lorentz transformation, the infinitesimal transformation gives us:
$$
\delta x^\mu = \epsilon^\mu_\nu x^\nu 
$$
$$
\delta \phi = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_{\mu\nu}M^{\mu\nu}\phi
$$
with $\epsilon_{\mu\nu} = -\epsilon_{\nu\mu}$ antisymmetric.
This gives us the conserved current (Noether's Theorem):

$$
J^\mu = \mathcal{L}g^{\mu\nu}\epsilon_{\nu\alpha}x^\alpha - \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}(\partial^\nu\phi)\epsilon_{\nu\alpha}x^\alpha + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}\epsilon_{\nu\alpha}M^{\nu\alpha}\phi
$$

My book says that is cannot factor out the antisymmetric term $\epsilon_{\nu\alpha}$ because I would lose the continuity equation $\partial_\mu J^\mu = 0 $. It says that $g^{\mu\nu}\epsilon_{\nu\alpha} \neq 0$ only for $\mu = \nu$. That is clearly obvious as the terms of $g^{\mu\nu} \neq 0$ only if $\mu = \nu$. My question is: since $g^{\mu\nu}$ is symmetric and $\epsilon_{\nu\alpha}$ antisymmetric shouldn't their product always be zero? I can't seem to wrap my head around indices, I'm sorry if this is a noob question but tensors indices really do confuse me.

Comment: You aren't summing over both indices, which is the case where you would be correct.

Comment: I supposed it was something like that. But I can't understand how that product is made as $ g^{\mu\nu}\epsilon_{\nu\alpha}x^\alpha $ is not two matrices times a vector. I don't understand, given two matrices and a vector how to construct such product, which terms of $g$ and $\epsilon$ get taken?

Comment: @SummonedEgar by not understanding the product do you mean how to write out the summation? Einstein summation doesn't care for the ordering of objects in an expression as if you had to care about them as matrices, the summation makes it a matter of components.

Comment: Exactley, I would like to have the matricial representation of $g^{\mu\nu}$ and be able to multiply the elements of $\epsilon_{\nu\alpha}$ and $x^\mu$ such that I obtain $g^{\mu\nu}\epsilon_{\nu\alpha}x^\alpha$ as a vector

Comment: @SummonedEgar well the metric tensor is pretty straight forward to write as a matrix especially if you don't know the explicit components (for instance the top leftmost component is simply $g^{00}$.), same is true for the $\epsilon_{\nu\alpha}$ tensor although you at least know there are negative signs on elements below the main diagonal (if this was the levi-civita pseudo-tensor, you would know the explicit components of it).

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it turns out that I was lost in a glass of water. Given two matrices $A$ symmetric and $B$ antisymmetric it follows that:

$$
a^{\mu\nu}b_{\mu\nu} = 0 
$$

This is **NOT** the matrix multiplication $AB$ but a merely multiplication of all components. In general a matrix $C = AB $ is not symmetric nor antisymmetric, this is why

$$
g^{\mu\nu} \epsilon_{\nu\alpha}x^\alpha \neq 0
$$

As this object instead is exactely $ \boldsymbol{g \epsilon x} $ with $\boldsymbol{g}$ and $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$ matrices and $\boldsymbol{x}$ vector